# Target Unreachable, identifier "Bean Name" resolved to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I m getting below error. I m new to JSF.

```
Jul 21, 2013 6:24:04 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
WARNING: /index.xhtml @18,65 value="#{userbean.userName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userbean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @18,65 value="#{userbean.userName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userbean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:284)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.jsf.dev.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "userbean")
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <center>
        <p:panel header="Login Form" style="width:350;">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
                    <h:outputLabel for="#{userbean.userName}" value="UserName" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{userbean.userName}" label="UserName"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel for="#{userbean.userPassword}" value="Password" />
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{userbean.userPassword}"></h:inputSecret>
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Login"
                        action="#{userbean.login}"></h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
        <div>
            <h:messages></h:messages>
        </div>
    </center>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which scope does your UserBean has?

Comment: Please post "faces-config.xml" and "web.xml"

Answer (score 4):

In [`h:outputLabel`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLabel.html), the `for` attribute must evaluate to String in an earlier phase of the JSF lifecycle than when the expression `"#{userbean.userName}"` can be evaluated. Therefore, you need to give it a String value like this:

```
<h:outputLabel for="userName" value="UserName" />
<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{userbean.userName}" label="UserName"/>
```

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-intro006.htm#BNAQQ) about JSF lifecycle:

> **Restore View Phase**
>   During this phase, the JavaServer Faces implementation builds the view of the page ...
>   If the request for the page is an initial request, the JavaServer
>   Faces implementation creates an empty view during this phase and the
>   lifecycle advances to the Render Response phase, during which the
>   empty view is populated with the components referenced by the tags in
>   the page.

So, the bean value is evaluated not before the Render Response phase, when the (empty) view has already been built.

Comment: Have changed the code as you said. but still getting same error after click the button

Comment: And you have changed correspondingly the second `<h:outputLabel>` for the `<h:inputSecret>`, I guess.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks a lot have resolved the issue i just run it with maven goal tomcat:run-war instead of tomcat:run

Comment: good call Shankar, this worked for me also this is my run command in total "clean install tomcat7:run-war" If anybody can explain why this fixes this particular problem, it would be helpful